# How To access sharepoint web Applicataion externaly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping

I created web Application  using Share Point and its working on LAN network.

Now I want to get access to web  Application  through Internet.

How can I do it any suggestion's ?

Comment: Web App means Web application..?

Comment: yes web application

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the following:

1. Get a internet available static IP address for you infrastructure from your internet services provider
2. Get a public domain name and make Nameserver entries to move traffic to your infrastructure
3. Configure firewall, reverse proxy and load balancer to allow traffic to reach your server. These are recommendations. however if you do not have them (very dangerous) you can simply map traffic to your server for the domain name
4. Configure "Alternate Access Mapping" to use for that domain in central administration. You may need to configure server mappings in search as well.
5. Extend web application on public domain name, install SSL certificates and so on.

Comment: I want to access my sharepoint web application through internet.

Comment: You will need to do the following:
1. Get a internet available static IP address for you infrastructure from your internet services provider
2. Get a public domain and make Nameserver entries to move traffic to your infrastructure
3. Configure firewall, reverse proxy and load balancer to allow traffic to reach your server. These are recommendations. however if you do not have them (very dangerous) you can simply map traffic to your server for the domain name
4. Configure "Alternate Access Mapping" to use for that domain

Comment: Can i access it without using domain name ??

Comment: You may do it with static IP address with rest of the settings. But it is not recommended specially when SSL certificates do not work with IP address.

Comment: I access my central admin page using IP and port.

Comment: I don't use any domain for this

Comment: It is not required in intranet but when you are on internet.. i.e. you want to access it from anywhere in world using any ISP provider.. then we need domain names and since it is a business application, SSL will be required.

Comment: I know your right but without ssl is it possible or not ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55878/discussion-between-parag-yelonde-and-alok-kumar-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

we can use  alternate access mappings  for this purpose. Please check the   msdn article [Configure alternate access mappings for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx)

Comment: It shows Invalid Host Error

Comment: First we need a public IP with Host name ( ex: www.abc.com ) then only we need to configure in alternate access mappings. you need to buy this hosting address and  the need to update in alternate access mappings.

Comment: I want to access web application using IP ,

Comment: because i access my central admin page using internet but when i try to access web application it gives me error "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname"

Comment: please add the detials of the web application url and domain details in hosts file located in the location C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: I didn't get you